# Magento model object created successfully in Windows throws an error in Linux

Tags: php, magento

I have the following error occur in my custom module :

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setData() on a non-object in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/app/code/local/Phparrow/Hello/controllers/IndexController.php

My code is as follows -

## config.xml

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <hello>
                <class>Phparrow_Hello_Block</class>
        </hello>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <hello>
            <class>Phparrow_Hello_Helper</class>   
        </hello>
    </helpers>
        <models>
            <hello>
                <class>Phparrow_Hello_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>hello_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </hello>
            <hello_mysql4>
                <class>Phparrow_Hello_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>        
                    <hello>
                        <table>hello</table>
                    </hello>
                </entities>
            </hello_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <hello_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Phparrow_Hello</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </hello_setup>
            <hello_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </hello_write>
            <hello_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </hello_read>
        </resources>
</global>
```

## magento\app\code\local\Phparrow\Hello\Model\Hello.php

```
<?php
class Phparrow_Hello_Model_Hello extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function _construct(){
        print 'test';
       $this->_init('hello/hello');
    print 'test1';
    }
}
```

## magento\app\code\local\Phparrow\Hello\Model\mysql4\Hello.php

```
<?php
class Phparrow_Hello_Model_Mysql4_Hello extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('hello/hello', 'hello_id');
    }
}
```

## magento\app\code\local\Phparrow\Hello\Model\mysql4\Hello\Collection.php

```
<?php
class Phparrow_Hello_Model_Mysql4_Hello_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract
{
    public function _construct(){
        $this->_init('hello/hello');
    }
}
```

## magento\app\code\local\Phparrow\Hello\controllers\IndexController.php

```
class Phparrow_Hello_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    { 
     $model1= Mage::getModel('hello/hello');
     echo get_class($model1);
     $model1->setData('name'->'Harsh','contact'->'8445895621');
     $model1->save();
    }
}
```

I have a hello table have that has three fields:

> hello_id, name, contact

Why would this not work in Linux when it successfully executes in Windows?

Comment: Try clear All caches from magento admin. Also check for compilation mode from admin, It should be Off.

Comment: Thanks for answer I had clear all caches and compilation mode already off but still issue is exist

Comment: $model1->setData('name'=>'Harsh','contact'=>'8445895621');

Comment: I have done this way but still error coming

Comment: I am not sure but possibly you have named the same "hello" inner. try one of them as "hello1".

Comment: I have renamed it "hello1" but still issue is there model object not create it will created in windows successfully but in Linux it gives error

Comment: Thanks Disha I have logout and login back and again enable and disable compilation mode and it work

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this has to do with your path or file naming, make sure that the files and folders are named *exactly* as you typed it here.

Windows doesn't care much and would probably serve up the file HelLo.php or hELLO.php just fine when the autoloader tried to find the model.

Comment: Thanks Yes file name and folder name same as here i have to copy path from there already exist.

Comment: Thanks yes my folder and file is same as typed here.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to save the data in model. You need  to make an array of data and pass in `setData()`

```
class Phparrow_Hello_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    { 
     $model1= Mage::getModel('hello/hello');
     $data = array('name'=>'Harsh','contact'=>'8445895621');
     $model1->setData($data);
     $model1->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Yes but my problem is Mage::getModel('hello/hello'); it will return blank or null instead of object